# WordPress using incorrect path for CSS in admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress is installed in a `blog` subfolder on the root of my server. I've installed many WordPress before and I can't find why it is happening.

When I log in to the admin area, the CSS doesn't load. When I look at the source, I see it tries to load : `http://contesk.dev/blog/wp-admin//wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load=admin-bar,buttons,media-views,wp-admin&ver=3.5.2`

It of courses gets an error 404. `/wp-admin/` is present twice in the url and I can find why and how to correct it. My blog url is properly set to `http://contesk.dev/blog` in the settings.

Tell me if you need more details, I'm not sure of what could be useful informations or not.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Search for that double `/wp-admin/` in the database with phpmyadmin and see if you can find it.

Also look in .htaccess for rewrite rules that might be causing that.

And reupload fresh copies of wp-admin and wp-includes; maybe some files were damaged in upload.